# For loop using two variables?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, postman

I am working on some code where I have two variables with several different teams in them. I am new to JS and can't seem to understand how to print the value of both variables in the same for loop.

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json();
let home_team = []
let away_team = []
let home_team_id = []
let away_team_id = []
//console.log(jsonData)
jsonData.games.forEach((b)=>{
    home_team.push(b.home.name)
    away_team.push(b.away.name)

})

pm.environment.set("Home_Team",home_team)
pm.environment.set("Away_Team",away_team)
//console.log(pm.environment.get("Home Team"))
//console.log(pm.environment.get("Away Team"))

for (const element of home_team) {
  console.log(element + "VS" + away_team);
}
```

Now I know the code above will not run, I am just showing what I would like printed to console, I can't figure out how to add a second element that references away_team in the same looop. With that said when I set my for loop to

```
for (const element of home_team) {
  console.log(element);
}
```

It prints my list of home teams with no issues but I really am looking for a loop that prints both my home and away team, the list sizes are the same and always will be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of data is going to reside in the `home_team`? Strings or objects?

Comment: Since list sizes are the same then just use an ordinary for loop according to the length of one of the lists and acees both by the index

Comment: @PraneetDixit -- it would be strings

SaymoinSam -- Okay I will try that,  that's what I can't seem to find an example of (or at least realize that's what I'm looking at) working on my skills everyday!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an indexed for loop

```js
for(let i = 0;i < home_team.length; i++) {
  console.log(home_team[i] + "VS" + away_team[i]);
}
```

You can also use `forEach`

```
home_team.forEach((item, index) => console.log(item + "VS" + away_team[index]));
```

Comment: Very much appreciated, I think I have a hard time wrapping my head around being able to use the single "home_team" length to iterate both lists, but I know understand since both lists are the same size, then yes. This was easy to follow and appreciate the foreach option as well! @SaymoinSam

Answer (score 1):

If both of your arrays contain same number of items, then you can use an ordinary for loop with accessing each item with the same index as below -

```js
let home_team = ["A", "B", "C"];
let away_team = ["D", "E", "F"];

for(let i=0; i<home_team.length; i++){
  console.log(`${home_team[i]} VS ${away_team[i]}`);
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use multiple counters in a for loop as below (though you won't need this now -

```js
let home_team = ["A", "B", "C"];
let away_team = ["D", "E", "F"];

for(let i=0,j=2; i<home_team.length; i++, j--){
  console.log(`${home_team[i]} VS ${away_team[j]}`);
}
```

Comment: Wish I could say both fixed my issue, they did. Thank you very much @Praneet